# Python 2.7 -getting started

Tags: python-2.7

Question :I am trying to get back to programming after years. I had trouble understanding and executing 1.2 of this webpage :http://anandology.com/python-practice-book/getting-started.html

```
anand@bodhi ~$ python hello.py
hello, world!
anand@bodhi ~$
```

---

```
# This is helloworld program
# run this as:
#    python hello.py
print "hello, world!"
```

---

How do I access or save a program in a directory using ipython notepad or jupyter?
Can someone please help?
I tried using it on python notebook version 2.7 but I could not.
May be a dumb question but first step may be the scariest one for me.

Comment: what is your code and what errors are you getting? please update your question.